# How to improve Jackson objectMapper deserialize performance?

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, jackson

I use kafka send quote message, qps is up to 50w, the consumer can handle it, but just only deserialize message, the CPU utilization up to 70!
Anybody knows how to optimize it?

Here is the deserialize code:

```
public class QuoteMessageDeserializer implements Deserializer<RawQuote> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public QuoteMessageDeserializer() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {

    }

    @Override
    public RawQuote deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        try {
            QuoteMessage msg = objectMapper.readValue(data, QuoteMessage.class);
            return msg.getData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           ……
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

I try to use AfterBurner,but it doesn't work to lower cpu utilization

```
public QuoteMessageDeserializer() {
  objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  objectMapper.registerModule(new AfterburnerModule());
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Kafka comes with a Jackson json serializer already. Why write your own?

Comment: I use kafka JsonDerializer(it  also use objectMapper),but it doesn't work for lower cpu,so I doubt that if has any more optimization for objectMapper

Comment: If you really care about cpu utilization, I'd suggest not using Java. Kafka clients exist for lots of languages